# The Seat Allocation Question$(7!)(8P3)$ (Permutations)

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are $10$ guys, $3$ of them are teachers. There are $10$ seats.Find the ways of any $2$ of the teachers sit together.

I have read it over and over again, but I still don't understand how it works. Thank you for your helping.

Comment: Are you asking for the number of ways any two of the teachers sit together or the number of ways no two of the teachers sit together?  The factor $7!P(8, 3)$ represents the number of ways no two of the teachers sit together.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes, I have noticed it, I was wrong for that, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9 positions to choose the 'two teachrs togethr', for 2 of them anothrr teachr will have 7 ways to sit separately, fir the other 7 -6. Now you need to select 2 teachrs out of 3 and muktiply by 2 because two selecred teachrs can intrchange their poditions. After this, multiply by 7!

Comment: um, this is a good way to understand it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Youa re welcome

Comment: anyway, do you know why the answer given includes a 8 in the $8P3$ ?

Comment: Im sory What is 8p3?

Comment: because the suggested answer is $(7!)(8P3)$, I am curious that how come the process can be compressed as such a short answer

Comment: I see, but what does 8p3 mean?

Comment: Forget this, there is something wrong in the answer, thanks again

Comment: The solution i get is 8!3!7

Answer (score 1):

The solution $7\cdot$ $^8P_3$ (for no two teachers sit together) is correct.

Denoting non-teachers by $N$,  see that there are $8$ permissible places (gaps) for the teachers

$_ N _ N _ N _ N _ N _ N _ N _$

So teachers can be placed in $^8P_3$ ways, and the others permuted in their positions in $7!$ way,

yielding ans = $7!\cdot$ $^8P_3$

Comment: By the way, the $P$ in $^8P_3$ stands for permutations. Here we choose the places for and arrange the 3 teachers, $\binom83\cdot3!$

Comment: ah.....so that is the answer for no two teacher sit together, thanks for the explanation

Comment: You're welcome !